# Grouping command in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and there are some things that I need to be clarified.

Lets say this is the data, `DeathYear`, `Age`, `Gender` and `Country` are all columns in an excel file.
[image]

```
df.groupby(['Gender','DeathYear']).mean()
```

This command will return the follwing

[image]

As shown in the picture, it lists each gender and each death year with the average age of the dead people in each year. my question is, why did it show the average age even though I did not type it in the command?

I know my question may be silly but any answer would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean` will calculate the means of every numeric column other than those used for grouping.

Take the example in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
...                   'B': [np.nan, 2, 3, 4, 5],
...                   'C': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2]}, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

>>> df.groupby('A').mean()
     B         C
A
1  3.0  1.333333
2  4.0  1.500000
```

In that case, both column `B` and `C` are numeric, so their means are automatically calculated.

In your example, `Gender` and `DeathYear` are used for grouping and `Country` is not numeric. `Age` is the only column whose means could be calculated.

Comment: Thank you so much this was really helpful, have a nice day.

Comment: @Morgpan Please don't forget to accept this answer If you find it helpful :)